# How do I reactivate a django server?

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django web development in python and I'm currently following a course on building a simple django website.

The problem is, I went to sleep and decided to shut down my computer. And now I think I need to reactivate the website or something because the website just says 'This site can't be reached'.

I opened up the code and I'm not sure if I'm suppose to write a certain command in the terminal or something. The terminal is empty when before it was running the website and had stuff there.

I do understand that it is going to stop
running the website when I shut down my computer because it's my computer hosting it, but I just need to know how to start running it again.

So how do I 're-activate' a django website?

Comment: I assume you're still under development, so `./manage.py runserver` in the right directory? You should probably have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate your virtual environment first and then run your Django server.

To activate a Python virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Note: Here "venv" is your virtual environment folder name

To run your Django server go to the project directory and run the below command

```
python manage.py runserver 
or
python3 manage.py runserver
```